# Jest exact object matching

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is there a function with a similar API to `expect.toMatchObject()`, but that will throw errors if the `expected` and `received` don't have the exact same set of keys, i.e a function `toExactMatchObject` such as

```
expect({a: 1, b: 2, c:3}).not.toExactMatchObject({a: expect.any(Number), b: expect.any(Number)}) // -> Should pass
```

This seems like a very frequent use-case, yet I can't find anything in the official documentation.

Comment: @slideshowp2 That appears to work. Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it? I still think there is value in my question for the way it is phrased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The imaginary `toExactMatchObject` should be equivalent to [.toEqual(value)](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#toequalvalue) Matcher

> Use `.toEqual` to compare recursively all properties of object instances (also known as "deep" equality).

```js
expect({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }).not.toEqual({ a: expect.any(Number), b: expect.any(Number) })
```